# Getting Internal Error 500 using MKNetworking Image Upload PHP

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, upload, nsurlerrordomain

I have switched from using the normal way to upload images (Didnt have it working then) to using MKNetworking to assist me with the uploading process, im using this way because i have found i get better error responses and its helping resolve my issues. I have gotten a NSLog response with an error reading

```
2013-05-03 10:52:25.961 atmebeta[2420:907] Returning num rows
2013-05-03 10:52:25.967 atmebeta[2420:907] Returning num sections
2013-05-03 10:52:34.607 atmebeta[2420:907] -[MKNetworkEngine reachabilityChanged:] [Line 198] Server [atmeapp.com] is reachable via Wifi
2013-05-03 10:52:37.066 atmebeta[2420:907] -[MKNetworkOperation operationFailedWithError:] [Line 1345] Friday, May 3, 2013, 10:52:37 AM Pacific Daylight Time
Request
-------
curl -X POST "http://atmeapp.com/addavatar.php" -d "email=ooo@ooo.com"
--------
Response
--------
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie_8.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="block_error">
        <div>
            <h2>Error 500 Internal Server Error</h2>
            <p>The web server is misconfigured please contact aaron@teknologenie.com</p>
<p>Please try to access the site later.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
, [The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 500.)]
2013-05-03 10:52:37.072 atmebeta[2420:907] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 500.)" UserInfo=0x1d993d40 {Accept-Ranges=bytes, Server=Apache, Content-Length=693, Content-Type=text/html, Date=Fri, 03 May 2013 17:52:34 GMT}
2013-05-03 10:52:37.102 atmebeta[2420:907] -[MKNetworkOperation operationFailedWithError:] [Line 1353] State: 0
```

I can successfully upload images through a html form, so im certain my php.ini is fine and im allowed to upload way more then what im asking to upload on my iPhone.

FileUploadDemoViewController.h

```
//
//  fileUploadDemoViewController.h
//  fileUploader
//
//  Created by Michael Roling on 5/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 NA. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "fileUploadEngine.h"

@interface fileUploadDemoViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) fileUploadEngine *flUploadEngine;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKNetworkOperation *flOperation;

@end
```

FileUploadDemoViewController.m

```
//
//  fileUploadDemoViewController.m
//  fileUploader
//
//  Created by Michael Roling on 5/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 NA. All rights reserved.
//

#import "fileUploadDemoViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface fileUploadDemoViewController ()

@end

@implementation fileUploadDemoViewController

@synthesize flUploadEngine = _flUploadEngine;
@synthesize flOperation = _flOperation;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *photoSourcePicker = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:  @"Take Photo",
                                        @"Choose from Library",
                                        nil,
                                        nil];

    [photoSourcePicker showInView:self.view];   
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)modalView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
                [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alert;
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                   message:@"This device doesn't have a camera." 
                                                  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];                
            }
            break;
        }            
        case 1:
        {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
                UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
                [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alert;
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                   message:@"This device doesn't support photo libraries." 
                                                  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];                
            }            
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.1);

    self.flUploadEngine = [[fileUploadEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"http://www.atmeapp.com" customHeaderFields:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [MyClass str], @"email",
                                       nil];      
    self.flOperation = [self.flUploadEngine postDataToServer:postParams path:@"/addavatar.php" ];
    [self.flOperation addData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) forKey:@"userfile" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:image];

    [self.flOperation addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation* operation) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [operation responseString]);
        /*   
            This is where you handle a successful 200 response
        */
    }     
    errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *errorOp, NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];        
    }];

    [self.flUploadEngine enqueueOperation:self.flOperation ];  

}
@end
```

fileUploadEngine.h

```
//
//  fileUploadEngine.h
//  fileUploader
//
//  Created by Michael Roling on 5/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 NA. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MKNetworkEngine.h"

@interface fileUploadEngine : MKNetworkEngine

-(MKNetworkOperation *) postDataToServer:(NSMutableDictionary *)params path:(NSString *)path;

@end
```

fileUploadEngine.m

```
//
//  fileUploadEngine.m
//  fileUploader
//
//  Created by Michael Roling on 5/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 NA. All rights reserved.
//

#import "fileUploadEngine.h"

@implementation fileUploadEngine

-(MKNetworkOperation *) postDataToServer:(NSMutableDictionary *)params path:(NSString *)path {

    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:path
                                              params:params
                                          httpMethod:@"POST"
                                                 ssl:NO];
    return op;     
}

@end
```

and last but not least, my php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `user` SET imagepath=? WHERE email=?")) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $albumname, $email);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $uploaddir = 'images/users/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    }
    $albumname = $uploadfile;
    $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close(); 
        }


    else {
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }

$mysqli->close();
```

im not getting any errors in the php logs on my servers,

Comment: You will need to provide the code for fileUploadEngine and flOperation for us to tell what is going on.

Comment: According to the curl command line output, the file to be posted is not making it to the MKNetworkOperation otherwise you would have a -F command line option listed.

Comment: Updated the question with the included files associated with the image uploading engine. Why do you think that is @CoryPowers

Comment: Try setting `self.flOperation.postDataEncoding == MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeURL` and provide the NSLog of the request, the curl command line should have an option for your userfile parameter

Comment: Also change the parameter to filename to be a string, `[self.flOperation addData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) forKey:@"userfile" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"avatar.jpg"]`

Comment: where am i adding the `self.flOperation.postDataEncoding == MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeURL` where `self.flOperation = [self.flUploadEngine postDataToServer:postParams path:@"/addavatar.php" ];` is?

Comment: Add it after the postDataToServer line

Comment: shooting a warning `Equality Comparison result unused ` is this anything to worry about?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error, should be `self.flOperation.postDataEncoding = MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeURL`

Comment: i did try that as well thinking maybe that was the case and that warning goes away but still same curl response. Can we continue this in a discussion chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29394/discussion-between-cory-powers-and-aaron-russell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by switching to AFNetwork heres my new code

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self->image setImage:image.image];
    [self  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://atmeapp.com"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 1);
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"email", [MyClass str],
                            nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/addavatar.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"userfile" fileName:[MyClass str] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

}
```

im not sure why it worked but whatever... very irritated. Thanks for everyones time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks basically right, i just did a MkNetworkKit / image upload in php. The only wrong thing i spot here is the line

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"email", [MyClass str]
```

You probably want to switch @"email" and [MyClass str], values should come before key when using dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys.

Here is my implementation (inside a subclass of MKNetworkEngine):

```
-(MKNetworkOperation*) uploadImage:(UIImage*)image onSuccess:(EmptyBlock)successBlock onError:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary dictionary]mutableCopy];
    [params setValue:@"[YOUR_VALUE]" forKey:@"[YOUR_KEY]"];
    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:@"[YOUR_PATH]" params:params httpMethod:@"POST"];
    [op addData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) forKey:@"userfile" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"[YOUR_FILENAME]"];

    [op onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
    if(successBlock) {
        successBlock();
    }
    } onError:^(NSError *error) {

        TFLog(@"RCNetworkEngine.uploadError:%@, error:%@", url, [error localizedDescription]);
        if(errorBlock)
            errorBlock(error);
    }];
    [self enqueueOperation:op];
    return op;
}
```

Comment: Im thinking maybe because of what my error message is saying then it has something to do with my php not recognizing its a image, or visa versa my objective-c sayings its not an image... do you think this could be a possibility? I'll try out your code, and switch up those params, any specific reason why they need to be flipped?

Comment: How did you write your h file using a subclass, i've never done that before

Comment: im offering a bounty to help me finish this portion of the app, i gave up on this part of the app while i finished the rest. Now its time to finish the image uploading. I'll be updating my question with some up to date code, im still receiving the `internal server error 500`

Comment: i also tried your solution but i just couldnt understand how to implement it correctly, or maybe i did but just but just having some server errors.